# Jsoup not connecting to webpage in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup

I am working on a project right now where I use jsoup in a class with the function retrieveMedia in order to return an ArrayList filled with data from the webpage. I run it in a thread since you shouldn't be connecting to URLs from the main thread. I run it and join it. However, it doesn't work (I tested the same code in Eclipse separate from Android Studio and it worked fine). It seems that no matter what I do I can't get jsoup to connect to the webpage. Below is my class MediaRetriever.

```
public class MediaRetreiever {

    public ArrayList<Media> retrieveMedia() {
        ArrayList<Media> mediaOutput = new ArrayList<Media>(); //Store each scraped post
        Thread downloadThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(<Website Im connecting to>).timeout(20000).get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to connect to webpage.");
                    mediaOutput.add(new Media("Failed to connect", "oops", "", "oh well"));
                    return;
                }
                
                Elements mediaFeed = doc.getElementById("main").getElementsByClass("node");

                for (Element e : mediaFeed) {
                    String title, author, imageUrl, content;
                    title=e.getElementsByClass("title").text().trim();
                    author=e.getElementsByClass("content").tagName("p").select("em").text().trim();
                    content=e.getElementsByClass("content").text().replace(author,"").trim();
                    Media media = new Media(title, author, "", content);
                    mediaOutput.add(media);
                }
            }
        });
        downloadThread.start();
        try {
            downloadThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        
        return mediaOutput;

    }
}
```

Running this class's method from another class and it doesn't ever connect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that the problem persists only in Android, it looks like that you should add the user agent string to your request - first get the user agent string of a browser that displays correctly the site, and then add it to the request:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(<Website Im connecting to>)
           .userAgent("your-user-agent-string")
           .timeout(20000).get();
```

And as a sidenote - if you are catching exception, don't print your own error message - print the original message, it may be very useful.